# Is there any way of eliminating the nested loops to prevent time execution error

Tags: python-3.x

how to make the code more efficient by using list comprehension or using itertools in python because this program gives timeexecution error for large input datasets.

```
    n=0
    k=0
    v='AEIOU'
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(string)+1):
            a = string[i:j]
            #print(a)
            if (a[0] == 'A') or  (a[0] == 'E') or (a[0] == 'I') or (a[0] == 'O') or (a[0] == 'U'):
                n+= 1
            else:
                k+=1
    if n>k:
        print('Kevin'+' '+str(n))
    elif n<k:
        print('Stuart'+' '+str(k))
    else:
        print('Draw')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)
```

Please check the question from this link
https://solution.programmingoneonone.com/2020/06/hackerrank-the-minion-game-problem-solution-python.html

I would appreciate it if you please explain the solution to the program as I am totally new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is:

```
def isVowel(c):
  if c in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']:
     return True
  return False


Kevin=0
Stuart=0
for i in range(len(s)):  #s is the input string 
    a=len(s)-i
    if isVowel(s[i]):    
        Kevin+=a
    else :
        stuart+=a
#check who has scored more he is the winner.
```

This works because, suppose for a string BANANA:

B is consonant so, we have to include all the strings starting with B.

B,BA,BAN.... so we will have total of (n-indexOf(B)) numbers of strings = 6-0 = 6 pts for stuart
A is vowel,
all strings with A = n-indexOf(A)=6-1=5 so 5 pts for kevin.

You dont have to explicitly check the numbers of times current substrings appear in the string as you will be iterating over all of them.

for example,

total pts for Kevin =

> pts for A at : Index(1) + Index(3) + Index(5)

total pts = (6-1) + (6-3) + (6-5) = 9

Comment: Beautifully explained,
❤

Comment: Thank you! if you like the explanation then accept it as Answer.